# Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port on Centos 6

Tags: ssh, centos-6, ssh-tunnel

I have a problem with port forwarding in centos 6, when i do:

```
ssh -v -R root@hostname:19999:localhost:22 root@hotname
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 19999
```

The ssh session starts but i cannot use it as a tunnel, the complete output is this:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to hostname [ip.ip.ip.ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'hostname' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
hostname's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Remote connections from root@hostname:19999 forwarded to local address localhost:22
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com

debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen 19999, connect localhost:22
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 19999
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Sun Jul 21 17:24:54 2013 from 172.16.63.56
```

during the connection i get in /var/log/secure the messages:

```
Jul 21 18:30:09 localhost sshd[11816]: Accepted password for root from 172.16.63.56 port 52035 ssh2
Jul 21 18:30:09 localhost sshd[11816]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 21 18:30:09 localhost sshd[11816]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener: getaddrinfo(root@hostname): Name or service not known
```

I can do the same command from another pc with ubuntu and it works perfectly, and i am sure that port 19999 is free. What can i do?

Comment: Have you checked the logging that occurs on the SSHD side?

Comment: where do i find it?

Comment: There may be something in /var/log/messages, or possibly in /var/log/secure.

Comment: i have added the message given bu the host in /var/logs/secure

Comment: How are you sure that 19999 is free?  netstat output?

Comment: because i tried numerously port and always netstat gave nothing on that port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try leaving off the "root@" portion of the `-R` argument:

```
ssh -v -R hostname:19999:localhost:22 root@hostname
```

With the four-parameter version of `-R`, the four parameters are the address and port to listen for connections on the remote host, and the address and port to forward to from the local host.

You're giving a value of "root@hostname" as the remote bind host/address. This value should just be a hostname or IP address; `ssh` doesn't expect this value to include a username. `ssh` is probably trying to look up the entire string "root@hostname" as a hostname and failing.

Comment: Thank you buddy, you are my hero! that error completely confuse me.
I hope this question will save hours of work for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggeling with this same issue on RHEL7, but additionally complicated with that the user I was connecting to was a SElinux confined as "user_u". The audit.log was logging these:

```
23. 12/09/2015 12:24:40 sshd user_u:user_r:user_t:s0 49 tcp_socket name_bind system_u:object_r:unreserved_port_t:s0 denied 8595602
24. 12/09/2015 12:24:40 sshd user_u:user_r:user_t:s0 49 tcp_socket name_bind system_u:object_r:unreserved_port_t:s0 denied 8595603
```

but it always takes me a while before figuring out I should be looking there :-)

To fix this, I had to use a port in the ephemeral_port_t range.

```
SELinux Port Type              Proto    Port Number
ephemeral_port_t               tcp      32768-61000
ephemeral_port_t               udp      32768-61000
```